# iOS App is creating two UIWindow

Tags: ios, uiwindow

I was refactoring an existing project to move away from using .storyboards and removed the initial main interface in .plist, but for some reason the app is creating two instances of UIWindow.

[image: UIWindows]

I have no idea on why this is happening, and the result of this is when I do create my actual UIWindow and use `makeKeyAndVisible()` for a second I get a black screen until the actual `rootViewController` becomes visible, this happens because in that split of a seconds it shows the first UIWindow which color is `nil`. If someone has any idea on why this is happening I would appreciate a bunch ;)

**EDIT 1:**

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

    window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    appCoordinator.start()

    return true
}
```

AppCoordinator.swift

```
func start() {
        let mainVC = UIStoryboard(storyboard: .main).instantiateInitialViewController()
    window.backgroundColor = .white
    window.rootViewController = mainVC
    window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Comment: Show your AppDelegate code?

Comment: @DonMag added the appDelegate code :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't duplicate the "double instance" of `UIWindow` using typical code for running without a "Main Interface" defined. I assume you're seeing that in Debug View Hierarchy? How are you assigning `window` inside `appCoordinator`?

Answer (score 0):

Check that "Main Interface" is empty:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the comment, Yes it is :)